# Android: OnClick not work when override onClick in customView

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view. My custom view extended from `RelativeLayout`:

```
public class CircleProgressButton extends RelativeLayout {...
```

In my Custom view i have a button :

```
private void initView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.ProgressButton, 0, 0
    );
    try {
        progressHeight = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_height, progressHeight);
        progressWidth = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_width, progressWidth);
        progressIconSuccess = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_iconSuccess, R.drawable.ic_done);
        progressIconFail = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_iconfail, R.drawable.ic_fail);
        progressText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_text);
        progressBackgroundImage = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_button_background);
    } finally {
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    initButton();
    initProgressBar();
    initImageView();
}
    private void initButton() {
        button = new AppCompatButton(getContext());
        LayoutParams button_params = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        button_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        button.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        button.setText(TextUtils.isEmpty(progressText) ? "Button" : progressText);
        button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        StateListDrawable background = new StateListDrawable();
        background.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, progressBackgroundImage);
//        background.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, progressBackgroundImagePressed);
        button.setBackground(background);
        button.setClickable(false);
/*        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (imageView.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) imageView.setVisibility(GONE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        });*/
        addView(button);
    }
```

Now i attached my custom view to fragment layout :

```
<com.tazik.circleprogressbutton.CircleProgressButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_save"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    app:progress_height="30"
    app:progress_width="30"
    app:progress_text = "@string/save_btn"
    app:progress_iconfail="@drawable/ic_fail"
    app:progress_iconSuccess="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:progress_button_background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

In my fragment i bind fragment layout like this:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_marhaleh, container, false);
    binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener(v->{
        Log.i("======", "onSaveClicked: ");
        // do my stuff
    });
```

After running application and clicked on `btnSave` log is appearing on logcat.

Now i want to override OnClick in my custom view so in order, in my custom view i implemented `View.OnClickListener` :

```
public class CircleProgressButton extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener {
private OnClickListener listener;

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable View.OnClickListener l) {
    listener = l;
}
```

And i override onClick:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(listener != null){
        if (imageView.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) imageView.setVisibility(GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
   }

}
```

Now after running app when i clicked on `btnSave` log is not appearing that's mean

```
 binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener(v->{
    Log.i("======", "onSaveClicked: ");
    // do my stuff
});
```

not working? What is happening?

Comment: Maybe it is related to this line  
        'button.setClickable(false);'

Comment: I remove `button.setClickable(false);` and nothing is changed but when back  `button.setClickable(false);` and remove `@Override
    public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable View.OnClickListener l) {
        listener = l;
    }` on clicked on fragment worked@Emir

Comment: but `onClick` method that override in custom class not called @Emir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this worked for me, in class CircleProgressButton add this funtion:

```
private void init(){
    setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

and call init() on all constructors.
remove this one

```
@Override
public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable View.OnClickListener l) {
 listener = l;
}
```

edit this method like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (imageView.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) imageView.setVisibility(GONE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}
```

trigger button onclick

```
binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            binding.btnSave.onClick(v);
            Log.i("======", "onSaveClicked: ");
            //code
        }
    });
```

after this should be work

Comment: do remove `@Override
public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable View.OnClickListener l) {
 listener = l;
}`? @Александр Волошиновский

Comment: dude this my some part of my fragment and it's layout : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jRckFtZNv6/   i got this error `/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the proper callback class for android:onClick. Tried android.view.View but it has 0 abstract methods, should have 1 abstract methods.` @Александр Волошиновский

Comment: I do but `onClick` that override on my custom class not called at all . Just `     binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener(v->{
            Log.i("", "onCreateView: ");
        });` in main class called. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hznKj5N3ww/  @Александр Волошиновский

Comment: this is because you override this method

Comment: nee to change setOnclickListener in this way: binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener(new CircleProgressButton(getContext()){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                super.onClick(v);
                Log.d("test_onclick",getContext().toString());
                /////
            }
        });

Comment: check my last comment

Comment: Thanks dude but when called custom view's .onClick() I do not know why progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE) not shown in button!!! @Александр Волошиновский

Comment: i know , just now i solved few second.., I made a small mistake

Comment: I updated this answer check last part of code ==>http://prntscr.com/op2utg

Comment: It is working but in this way, it's not to need implements View.OnClickListener on custom view, it's just need to create a method like `onclick()` and call method from fragment like `binding.btnSave.onClick();` @Александр Волошиновский

Answer (score 0):

if you use databinding try this one

```
<com.tazik.circleprogressbutton.CircleProgressButton
 android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.click()}"
 .........../>
```

Comment: I do this, but i want to that when circleprogressbutton clicked some stuff in custom view started for example `progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);` so i need override onClick in custom view @Александр Волошиновский

Comment: I used `android:onClick="@{(view)->handlers.onSaveClicked(view)}"`.It just call my method not call onClick method in my custom class @Александр Волошиновский

Comment: i added new answer check please